# PHP get forms data with one button when the form is inside a loop fetched from database

Tags: php, html

I have a query which fetches data from the database within a loop, for each instance of loop a form is created, now I want to get the value of each forms data within the loop itself and check if it matches with its corresponding row's column in the database:

for  eg:

```
<?php
    $marks = 0;
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resut)) {
        echo  '<form method="POST" action="">
        <div  class="col-sm-8" id="question">'.$row['question'] .'</div>
        <input type="radio" placeholder="" name="answer" value = "true" id=""> True
        <input type="radio" placeholder="" name="answer" value = "false" id=""> false
    </form>';

      if (isset($_POST['save'])){ // this is the submit button present outisde the loop at last
        if ($_POST['answer'] == $row['answer']) {
            $marks++;
        } else {
            echo "incorrect";
        }
      }
    }
?>
<form role="form" action="" method= "POST">
    <button name ="save" id=" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is that I have a column in database which I can get by  `$row['answer']` within the loop. so I could check the forms data with  this row by  `if( $_POST['answer'] == $row['answer'])` .. .do smth...But the problem is that I have to keep the submit button outside the loop since there should only be only 1 submit button and if I put it outside the loop it is not working.

My attempts:

1. I tried to keep the form tag before the loop. if I do this then suppose there are 10 rows in database I would be needing 10 forms and 10 values taken within the loop. but then if I press the radio button in one of the rows the other would be deselected. so in my opinion the form tag should be inside the whole loop only.
2. I tried keeping the form submit button (present at last) inside the while loop within every instance of rows fetched. then again it would echo every button for every row which is not the motive. I just want one button for all the forms to be submitted and get values accordingly.
3. also I cannot do this check outside or in any other page since I have to check with every instance of the loop i.e. `$row['answer']` with every instance of forms radio button data i.e. `$_POST['answer']`.

Thank you for every response.

Comment: So what you do here is you load the correct answer from the database and compare it with the answer of the user? That is a wrong approach. You should do the answer checking after the form is submitted.

Comment: NO ! first of all the form present for the users itself is feched from the database. these are  actually questions  uploaded by  admin in the question table . later on it is fetched in the quiz.php . so the forms are generated within the loop

Comment: If I'm not wrong what you're trying to do here is display the questions and have the users answer them by choosing a radio button and clicking save. The problem with that logic is that `$_POST['answer']` will only save the last value it got so your current implementation won't work. what you need to do here is to store each of those answers in an array and use that array to check if that answer is correct.

Comment: there is not only one naswer each instance of loop has to match answer with resulting rows. which means each row of questions answer given by the user should match with the tables answer

Comment: You need to save the answers before you compare them with the data on the row. Not during the answer process. So the user will first answer the questions submit it and you then process the answers and compare it with your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send all the answers at once, you'll need to use a single form.

To do that, you can change the `name` of your `input` so that it's different for each question.

```
$marks = 0;
$idx = 0;
echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resut)) {
    ++$idx;
    echo
    '<div  class="col-sm-8" id="question">'.$row['question'].'</div>
    <input type="radio" placeholder="" name="answer'.$idx.'" value = "true" id=""> True
    <input type="radio" placeholder="" name="answer'.$idx.'" value = "false" id=""> False';

    if (isset($_POST['save']))  {   // this is the submit button present 
   outisde the loop at last 

        if ($_POST['answer'] == $row['answer']) {
            $marks++;
        } else {
            echo "incorrect";
        }
    }
}
echo '</form>';
```

You can also inject the `$idx` between brackets, which will give you a single `$_POST['answer']` entry, but which will be an array instead of a string. That array will contain all your answers assignated to the keys you injected as `$idx` :

```
<input type="radio" placeholder="" name="answer['.$idx.']" value = "true" id=""> True
<input type="radio" placeholder="" name="answer['.$idx.']" value = "false" id=""> False
```

Comment: so how should i take the form data , $_POST['answer'] or $_POST['answer'$idx] ??

Comment: @GauravMaharjan It's between `$_POST['answer1']` and `$_POST['answer'][1]`, depending on what you choose.

For cases where the information will be treated the same way and especially if you don't know how much you'll have, the `name="answer['.$idx.']"` method - thus allowing you to access to your data with `$_POST['answer'][1]`, `$_POST['answer'][2]` ... - is better and simpler to implement.